# ftp_connect times out after SSL install

Tags: php, ftp

ftp_connect was working fine until I installed the SSL cert. It tries to connect but then it times out.I do not care about using ftp_ssl_connect, just need ftp_connect. Using standard port 21. PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: It also seems wget hangs, never really connects

Comment: What software you are using for connect via FTP server? File Zilla?

Comment: Turns out the IP was blocked

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, the IP was blocked. Kinda new on here. Is there a way to mark this question as resolved?